# Joi validation display custom error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js, joi

Hi I am using  `"@hapi/joi": "^15.1.1"`. Unfortunately, I can't update to the latest Joi version right now.

This is my validation schema

```js
 const schema = {
    name: Joi.string()
      .allow("")
      .max(30),
    addLine1: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Address Line 1"),
    locality: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("City"),
    region: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("State"),
    zipCode: Joi.number()
      .required()
      .label("Zip Code"),
    phoneNo: Joi.string()
      .required("Required")
      .regex(/^[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$/)
      
  };
```

Then I validate and display the first error that occurred

```
const result = Joi.validate(this.state.addressDetails, this.schema, {
      abortEarly: true,
    });
 return const errors = result.error.details[0].message;
```

This works. The only problem is I want to display a custom error message instead of the default one.

Default error message for address is `"Address Line 1" is not allowed to be empty"`
Instead of this, I want to display `"Address is required!"`

For the regex default one is

```
phoneNo with value "555" fails to match the required pattern: /^[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$/
```

Instead, I want to display `please enter a valid phone number`

How could I achieve this with version `15.1.1`.
Newer versions `messages` thing won't help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out to return the message from the **[`.error`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=15.1.1#anyerrorerr-options)** callback

```
  addLine1: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Address Line 1").error(()=>'"Address Line 1" is not allowed to be empty'),
```