# Custom error messages with Joi validation

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

***TLDR:*** I was having problems with the `.messages()` and `.error()` functions. Turns out I was using `joi-browser` in codepen by accident. It also caused problems with adding `required()` to references (eg: `.valid(Joi.ref('password')).required()`)

---

***Original Question:***

I'm using this schema to try and receive the first error for each field when validating the whole form at once, but would like to also get custom error messages working:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  // Custom error message doesn't work
  username: Joi.string().label('Username').error(() => "Must be a string"),
  // Returns 1st error for each field
  email: Joi.string().email().label('Email').error(errors => errors[0]),
  password: Joi.string().label('Password').error(errors => errors[0]),
  confirmPassword: Joi.ref('password')
})
```

Example validate function

```
const validate = (data) => {
  const options = { abortEarly: false }
  const { error } = Joi.validate(data, schema, options);
  if(!error) return null;
  
  const errors = {};
  error.details.forEach(error => {
    errors[error.path[0]] = error.message
  })
  return errors;
}
```

As shown, my attempts to add a custom error message don't work

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666269/7396516) answer suggests using the syntax I'm using above to create a custom error:

`username: Joi.string().label('usernameValue').error(() => "Must be a string")`

but it doesn't seem to work for me

I've also tried other syntax in the [docs](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/v9.0.4/API.md#anyerrorerr):

`Joi.string().error(new Error('Was REALLY expecting a string'));`

but again with no luck

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65967046/7396516) looks promising, but I can't see anything in the docs about using (for example) `"string.min"` as a key for the error, and it also just throws an error saying that `messages` is not a function

Was just wondering what I've been missing? I'd really like to be able to combine a custom message with the first syntax that allows me to output the first message for every field

Thanks

*****Edit: New codepen link with better code***

- The new code now allows me to display custom messages on the form,
  See here: `setErrorFor(confirmPasswordField, 'Passwords must match');`
  but it would be nice to know how to do this with Joi

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/XWZKyME?editors=0011)

```js
//*********** Form Specific details ************
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const usernameField = document.getElementById('username');
const emailField = document.getElementById('email');
const passwordField = document.getElementById('password');
const confirmPasswordField = document.getElementById('confirm-password');

const fields = { usernameField, emailField, passwordField, confirmPasswordField };

const schema = Joi.object({
  username: Joi.string().label('Username').error(() => "Must be a string"),
  email: Joi.string().email().label('Email').error(errors => errors[0]),
  password: Joi.string().label('Password').error(errors => errors[0]),
  confirmPassword: Joi.ref('password')
})

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const username = usernameField.value.trim();
  const email = emailField.value.trim();
  const password = passwordField.value.trim();
  const confirmPassword = confirmPasswordField.value.trim();
  const data = { username, email, password, confirmPassword };
  
  const errors = validate(data);

  if(!errors) {
    Object.values(fields).forEach(field => setSuccessFor(field));
    return;
  } 
  
  if(errors.username) 
    setErrorFor(usernameField, errors.username); 
  if(errors.email)     
    setErrorFor(emailField, errors.email);
  if(errors.password)  
    setErrorFor(passwordField, errors.password);
  if(errors.confirmPassword) 
    setErrorFor(confirmPasswordField, 'Passwords must match');
})




// ************* Reusable validation code *************

const validate = (data) => {
  const options = { abortEarly: false }
  const { error } = Joi.validate(data, schema, options);
  console.log(error);
  if(!error) return null;
  
  const errors = {};
  error.details.forEach(error => {
    errors[error.path[0]] = error.message
  })
  return errors;
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
  
  small.innerText = message;
  
  formControl.className = 'form-control error';
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement;
  formControl.className = 'form-control success';
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: firebrick;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.form {
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

.form-control {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.form-control label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.form-control input {
  border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.form-control.success input {
  border-color: #2ecc71;
}
.form-control.error input {
  border-color: #e74e3c;
}
.form-control i {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px;
  right: 10px;
}
.form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
  color: #2ecc71;
  visibility: visible;
}
.form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
  color:  #e74e3c;
  visibility: visible;
}
.form-control small {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.form-control.error small {
  visibility: visible;
  color: #e74e3c;
}

.form button {
  background-color: firebrick;
  border: 2px solid lemonchiffon;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Create Account</h2>
  </div>
    <form action="" class="form" id="form">
      
      <div class="form-control">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
        <small>Error Message</small>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-control">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email@domain.com" id="email">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
        <small>Error Message</small>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-control">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
        <small>Error Message</small>
      </div>
      
      <div class="form-control">
        <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="confirm-password">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
        <small>Error Message</small>
      </div>
      
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `joi-browser` uses a pretty old version of `joi`, AFAICT. Have you considered not using that and instead using JOI?  You'll note in the repo it states it's deprecated, that it's old, and that JOI now supports browser environments.

Comment: Oh XD I had just quickly copied and pasted a cdn link for what I thought was Joi from someone else's demo because Codepen wasn't auto suggesting Joi. I didn't even think to check if it was joi-browser! It's late here now, but I'll test it tomorrow. Thanks though, think you're probably right

Comment: So Codepen doesn't seem to auto suggest Joi at all, and any CDN I can find seems to only have Joi browser available - but I used their sandbox and you're right, it does seem to have been the old browser version causing the issues as returning a new error works - thanks! If you put it in an answer I'll mark as correct if you like

Comment: You might be confusing the file name with the project name (and I might have been too, although the version was still quite old). I didn’t verify but it looks like https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/joi is correct.

Comment: No, I think you were right - think I was using the browser version. It all seems to be working now thanks!